# Wrapper to enclose several parts

Tags: sectioning

> How do you code a title level higher than `part` (say `book`)?

I actually want to attach several books, each with multiple parts without going through individual pdf generations.

Here is an example of architecture:

- Book 1

  - Part I

    - Chapter 1
    - Chapter 2
  - Part II

    - Chapter 1
    - Chapter 2
- Book 2

  - Part I

    - Chapter 1
    - Chapter 2

Comment: Maybe try with `titlesec`. You can see  §3.9. *Creating new levels and changing the class*, pp.10-11 in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation of a `book` section level made with `titlesec`, using the `\titlecass` command to define the new level. The books are added to the table of contents with `titletoc`, and at the beginning of a new book, the `part` and `chapter` counters are reset.

The formatting of a book title is defined with `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing`, and the formatting of a book title in the table of contents is defined with `\titlecontents`. Note that the formatting of the new level *has* to be defined with `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing`; there is no default formatting predefined for the new level.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\book}[-2]{page}
\newcounter{book}
\renewcommand{\thebook}{\Roman{book}}
\titleformat{\book}[display]{\vfill\centering\scshape\huge}{Book \thebook}{\baselineskip}{}[\vfill\vfill]
\titlespacing{\book}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlecontents{book}[1.8em]{\vspace{2\baselineskip}}{\scshape\large\contentslabel{1.35em}}{\hspace*{-1.35em}}{\hfill\scshape\large\contentspage}
\let\oldbook\book
\renewcommand{\book}{%
    \setcounter{part}{0}%
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
    \oldbook%
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

\book{First book}

\part{First part of first book}

\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{Even a subsection}

\part{Other part of first book}

\chapter{Again another chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{Another section}

\book{Second book}

\part{First part of second book}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{Another section}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

This example gives the following document structure.

[image]

Here's what the title of the first book looks like (it is alone on a page, like the title of a new part).

[image]